# javascript not working after upgrading to rails3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on my application to upgrade to rails 3.0.10, after getting rid of all warnings, none of my javascript code is working.

Here is what I have in my layout and config files

```
application.rb
config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails)

application.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>

Gemfile
gem 'jquery-rails'

$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.10
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i686-linux]
```

I followed javascript updates but my js doesn't seem to work. I must be missing some steps.

Comment: The only thing that Rails can do that can mess up your javascript is to not include the files. Have you run your site using Chrome or using Firebug in Firefox to see whether your files are being loaded and if they are what the error is?

Comment: There's also a generator script you need to run when installing jquery-rails - have you run that? Could be jQuery that's missing.

Comment: Thanks Russell. There was an error in one of my js file that I updated as part of upgrade. I fixed the error in my js file and its working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the jquery-rails gem on rails 3.0.10 you'll need the 'rails.js' file.

Find it here: https://raw.github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/master/src/rails.js

Copy that, name it '**rails.js**' and add it to your public/javascripts folder.

Then put this `<%= javascript_include_tag 'rails.js' %>` after your javascript defaults tag.